# pytest is not parsing command line arguments on windows <instead running all the tests>

Tags: python, command, pytest

I have 2.3.3 version of pytest running on windows. I have a test folder which contains bunch of test files like test1.py, test2.py, test3.py etc. If i open command prompt and navigate to this folder to run a particular test

pytest test1.py

Instead of just running test1.py, it is running all the tests in the folder. Like test1.py, test2.py, test3.py etc.
So pytest is not taking arguments and parsing them. I am seeing this only on windows. Does anyone know what is happening here?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this but what I'd do first would be check `PATH` for the pytest executable.  I'd except a Windows batch script, and continue investigation in the code, maybe that's where the args are lost or passed (quoted?) incorrectly.